# How to handle MISSING_PLUGIN_EXEPTION in Flutter with Firebase Core Plugin on IOS

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter

for several days I have tried to link my Flutter app with Firebase Database. But unfortunately, whenever I want to start debugging the compiler gives back a missing plugin exemption concerning the firebase_core package. I have already seen some entries referring to this issue here on stack overflow but none of them worked for me.
I have already followed the instruction steps by the installation guide on Firebase and included the Google Service File in my Xcode project.
I already did flutter clean, deleted the pods folder and the pod file.lock file in IOS, tried to include the Firebase SDK package by using the add package option in Xcode.
In the past, the connection between my Flutter project and the Firebase Database already worked but somehow it won't work now.
I think that my issue deals with the new step in the installation process for Firebase Connection when I am asked to make use of the Firebase SDK in Xcode.
In the following I'll add some more pictures for illustration. If someone had the same/a similar issue, it would be a huge help for me.

[error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxnu1.png)

[podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjcYf.png)

[main_dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJSD9.png)

[Xcode runner workspace including google Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wguu.png)

[AppDelegate in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urTPX.png)

[pubspec yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcWL9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have now added some pictures to my post above, is this what you are looking for? Do you need some other screenshots?